# Установка пользовательского пакета в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, package

Скачал пакет, чтобы легче было писать шейдеры в визуал студио, но не знаю как его установить.

Папка с пакетом выгладит так:[image: пакет, который надо установить]

В README.md информации по установке нет. В вкладке "Расширения" в  визуалке не нашел кнопки, чтобы можно было добавить пакет из проводника

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarcinODev.ShaderUnitySupport - скачивайте пакет, а не исходники

Comment: спасибо, это помогло. Но все же монжо ведь скомпилировать исходник и добавить в визуалку?